# Есть ли алгоритм со сложностью O(n) для нахождения минимального количества перестановок элементов массива 1, чтобы массив 1 стал равен массиву 2?

Tags: python, массивы, алгоритм, сложность

Есть 2 массива, элементы которых от 1 до n:

```
current_array = [1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 7, 6]
expected_array = [6, 2, 4, 1, 3, 5, 7]
```

Чтобы current_array стал равен expected_array за минимальное количество перестановок элементов current_array влево, нужно переставить 3 элемента:

current_array -> [4, 1, 3, 5, 2, 7, 6] -> [2, 4, 1, 3, 5, 7, 6] -> [6, 2, 4, 1, 3, 5, 7]

[6, 2, 4, 1, 3, 5, 7] == expected_array

Переставить - значит, подвинуть элемент t на p позиций влево, где p не больше, чем текущее количество элементов слева от t.

Чтобы найти минимальное количество перестановок, я написал такой код:

```
n = 7
current_array = [1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 7, 6]
expected_array = [6, 2, 4, 1, 3, 5, 7]
counter = 0

for i in range(n):
    if current_array[i] != expected_array[i]:
        current_array.remove(expected_array[i])
        current_array.insert(i, expected_array[i])
        counter += 1

print(counter)
```

Но его сложность O(n^2), что довольно медленно. Я думал использовать [расстояние Левенштейна](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0), но его сложность при равных массивах тоже будет равна O(n^2).

Есть ли алгоритм для этой задачи, сложность которого будет O(n)?

Comment: Что вы называете "переставить"?

Comment: переставить элемент t на p позиций влево, где p не больше, чем текущее количество элементов слева от t.

Comment: Если только влево... Но условие "где p не больше, чем текущее количество элементов слева от t" странное, там дальше-то переставлять и некуда.

Comment: Для "expected_array = [3, 5, 2, 4, 7, 6, 1]" и "current_array = [1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 7, 6]" сначала передвинется влево 6 и станет [6, 1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 7], потом 7, 4, 2, 5, 3. В итоге, станет [3, 5, 2, 4, 7, 6, 1]

Comment: А Вам обязательно надо именно передвигать? Или можно сразу сформировать новый массив?

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов, в наборе перемещений вся сложность и состоит.

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов Передвигать, возможно, не обязательно. Ведь основная цель задачи - найти минимальное количество сдвигов элементов массива влево для того, чтобы массивы стали равны

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy это понятно.  Я пытался понять, что конкретно нужно - сформировать итоговый массив, или найти количество перемещений.

Comment: @BIT, спасибо, понятно.

Comment: Сложная задача. Знаю как решить её за *O(NNN)*. Как быстрее - не знаю.

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy Да. Непростая... Но в то же время интересная

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy А что значит O(NNN), не пойму? N^3 или что?

Comment: @rotabor, да. У нас есть *N^2* элементарных перестановок. Это рёбра графа (торчат из любой его вершины. То есть граф - регулярный степени *N^2*.). Надо найти на этом графе кратчайшый путь между массивами-перестановками. Есть соображения, что длина пути не будет длиннее *N*. Если искать целенаправленно (хе-хе, я ещё не придумал как), то за *N^3* можно построить путь.

Comment: Как вы представляете себе осуществление сдвига элементе на `p` позиций влево без сдвига вправо на одну позицию всех `p-1` элементов, которые были левее его? Или вы имеете в виду не массив, а связный список?

Comment: @avp Да, связанный список.

Comment: @BIT, тогда (если переходить из чистого мира высоких теорий на грешную практическую почву) надо бы принять во внимание, что адресоваться к элементу списка по номеру за O(1) не выйдет

Comment: @avp Нужно использовать массивы, решение есть.

Comment: @rotabor, ну (если вы о коде в своем ответе), вы же не делаете перестановки в исходном массиве, а создаете новый (сортировка подсчетом тоже выполняется за O(N), только она м.б. эффективна лишь для малого диапазона ключей)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для решения этой задачи нужно определить порядок элементов в исходном массиве относительно целевого. Те элементы, которые расположены не по порядку, нуждаются в перемещении.

```
sa = [1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 7, 6]
ta = [6, 2, 4, 1, 3, 5, 7]

n = len(sa)
t = [0] * n
for i in range(n):
    t[ta[i] - 1] = i 
counter = 0
m = t[sa[0] - 1]
for i in range(1, n):
    a = t[sa[i] - 1]
    if a < m:
        counter += 1
    else:
        m = a

print(counter)
```

-->

```
3
```

Другие примеры:

```
Src [1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 7, 6]
Tgt [7, 6, 1, 3, 5, 2, 4]

2

Src [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
Tgt [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

0

Src [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
Tgt [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

4

Src [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
Tgt [1, 2, 4, 3, 5]

1

Src [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
Tgt [1, 5, 4, 3, 2]

3
```

Если элементам некоего множества можно поставить в соотвествие элементы множества соотвествующего количества последовательных натуральных чисел, то упорядочивание элементов такого множества осуществляется просто индексацией.

Этот код выводит промежуточный результат для демонстрации принципа решения:

```
n = len(sa)
t = [0] * n
tmp = [0] * n
for i in range(n):
    t[ta[i] - 1] = i 
for i in range(n):
    tmp[i] = t[sa[i] - 1] 
counter = 0
m = tmp[0]
for i in range(1, n):
    if tmp[i] < m:
        counter += 1
    else:
        m = tmp[i]

print('  Src', sa)
print('  Tgt', ta)
print('Order', tmp, '-->', counter)
```

Comment: Если текущий массив будет [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], а ожидаемый массив будет [5, 4, 3, 2, 1], то ваш ответ будет 2, но правильный ответ 4, так как нужно переставить влево числа 2, затем 3, 4, 5. В итоге, станет [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

Comment: Поменял. Должно быть получше :-)

Comment: Ваше решение проходит все тесты и укладывается в линейную сложность.

Comment: Отлично! *(я тоже начал думать с массива позиций, но пытался почему-то поддерживать текущий минимум в недвиганной части, а оно вон как надо было)*

Comment: Избавился от одного промежуточного массива (списка).

Comment: @rotabor Спасибо. Вы крутой. Ваше решение работает)

Comment: Спасибо за такую оценку. Мне самому было интересно подумать над этим вопросом, как и другим людям, которые тут отметились.

Answer (score 2):

Код:

```
def simplify(p, q):
    r = [None] * len(q)
    for i, j in enumerate(q, start=1):
        r[j - 1] = i
    return tuple(r[j - 1] for j in p)


def count(r):
    n = len(r)
    i = 0
    j = 1
    k = 0
    while j <= n:
        if r[i] < j:
            i += 1
        else:
            if r[i] > j:
                k += 1
            j += 1
    return k


print(count(simplify(
    tuple(map(int, input().split())),
    tuple(map(int, input().split()))
)))
```

Немного теории. Решение в вопросе верное. Можно показать, что если найдена оптимальная последовательность ходов, то её можно поменять на последовательность той же длины, которая ставит первый элемент на место, затем второй и т.д. Так что идея о "сборке" решения слева направо верная, хотя требуются усилия чтобы это доказать.

Практика. Упростим задачу - так переименуем числа в массивах, чтобы второй приобрёл вид `1 2 3 ... n`. Например:

> ```
> 1 3 5 2 4 7 6    ->    4 5 6 2 3 7 1
> 6 2 4 1 3 5 7    ->    1 2 3 4 5 6 7
> ```

Ясно что исходная пара и новая пара решаются одним и тем же набором перемещений элементов - взаимное расположение элементов сохранилось.

Задача свелась к упорядочению массива слева направо и подсчёту числа шагов:

> ```
> 4 5 6 2 3 7 1
>  /---------/    # единица на первое место
> 1 4 5 6 2 3 7
>    /---/        # двойка на второе
> 1 2 4 5 6 3 7
>      /---/      # тройка на третье
> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
> ```

В коде в вопросе это делалось прямой модификацией первого массива. Можно обойтись без неё. Для этого один индекс заменим на пару: `i` и `j`.

> ```
> оригинальное     решение без
> решение          изменения
>                  массива
>
> i                i                 # i-тый элемент больше j (= 1)
> 4 5 6 2 3 7 1    4 5 6 2 3 7 1     # i не меняется
>                  j = 1             # увеличиваем j
>
>   i              i
> 1 4 5 6 2 3 7    4 5 6 2 3 7 1     # тоже самое для j = 2
>                  j = 2
>
>     i            i
> 1 2 4 5 6 3 7    4 5 6 2 3 7 1     # тоже самое для j = 3
>                  j = 3
>
>       i          i                 # i-тый элемент равен j (= 4)
> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7    4 5 6 2 3 7 1     # перенос не нужен
>                  j = 4             # двигаем и j и i
>
>         i          i
> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7    4 5 6 2 3 7 1     # снова равенство
>                  j = 5
>
>           i          i
> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7    4 5 6 2 3 7 1     # опять
>                  j = 6
>
>             i          i           # i-тый элемент меньше j (= 7)
> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7    4 5 6 2 3 7 1     # увеличиваем i чтобы пропустить
>                  j = 7             # мусор
>
>             i            i
> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7    4 5 6 2 3 7 1     # снова пропускаем мусор
>                  j = 7
>
>             i              i       # i-тый элемент равен j (= 7)
> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7    4 5 6 2 3 7 1     # перенос не нужен
>                  j = 7             # двигаем и j и i
>
>               i              i
> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7    4 5 6 2 3 7 1     # j вышел за пределы массива
>                  j = 8             # завершаем цикл
> ```

Answer (score 2):

А что если мы не будем передвигать массив, а сразу посчитаем для каждого элемента первого массива насколько далеко он находится от нужного положения, ведь если a стоит в первом массиве раньше чем во втором массиве, то передвинуть его можно только подставляя элементы перед ним.

Comment: стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос

Comment: "ведь если a стоит в первом массиве раньше чем во втором массиве, то передвинуть его можно только подставляя элементы перед ним" - это нехорошая идея, потому что требует перестановки неизвестно какого кол-ва элементов. Поэтому трогать его не нужно. И вообще, абсолютное местоположение элементов роли не играет, важно их местоположение относительно друг друга.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант без создания промежуточных списков со словарем и генератором. Не зависит от упорядоченности цифр от 1 до n.

```
def get_count(src: list[int], trg: list[int]) -> int:
    # Вариант генератора экономящий память за счет скорости
    # src_index_gen = (trg.index(src_item) for src_item in src)
    # Если размер памяти позволяет, то можно через словарь:
    trg_index = {n: i for i, n in enumerate(trg)}
    src_index_gen = (trg_index[src_item] for src_item in src)
    count: int = 0
    prev_item = next(src_index_gen)

    for next_item in src_index_gen:
        if prev_item > next_item:
            count += 1
        else:
            prev_item = next_item

    return count
```

Comment: К сожалению, первая строчка требует квадратичного времени

Comment: Вынесите `{...}` из `(...)`. Сложность станет линейной.